# Variable with other variables always prints to same line python

Tags: python, variables, printing

Why does a variable holding other variables print to just one line, even with explicitly listing sep and end?

```
var1 = 123
var2 = ("foo", "678)
var3 = 456
var4 = var1, var2, var3
print(var4)   # Or sep="\n"   Or end="\n"
print("var1 is ", var1, var2, var3)
```

Results either which way I seem to run this is:

```
(123, 'foo', 456)
123 foo 456
```

*Update - Ican do a work around like this, but callign on this multiple times is redundant.

```
print("var1 is: ", var1,
  "\nvar2 is: ", var2,
  "\nvar3 is: ", var3)
# Results were
var1 is:  123 
var2 is:  foo 
var3 is:  456
```

Without being able to store the new lines into a variable, I have to relist this method at every point, which is redundant. Using

```
print(*var4, sep='\n')
```

Breaks apart var2 (which is actually a dict on my script), resulting in output like:

```
123
foo
1
foo
2
var3
```

Comment: Same output, just no displayed as a tuple `(123, 'foo', 456)` went to 
`123 foo 456`.   Updated original to show what I am trying to get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print(*var4, sep='\n')
```

This will unpack the tuple, so `print` gets them as multiple arguments instead of as a single tuple argument. (This way it can actually use the separator.)

Comment: This worked for, but saw another follow up after running this.  My Var2 is actually a dictionary with two parts, so `print(*var4, sep='\n')` prints my dictionary list into two lines. Can the * be used to isolate which ones I want to break apart in that manner? I ended up just making a long list of variables and text to get it working for now.

Comment: @D-slr8 I'll need a better example inputs & desired outputs to answer that. There are various ways to break up dicts and I don't know which one you want.

Comment: all good now, I was able to get something working after some tinkering with the `print(*var4, sep='\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, but you could always do...

```
print('\n'.join(var4))
```

Comment: This returned an error `TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, int found`.  Not sure if this is because I am actually running this print from inside function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess you could replace the tuple with a `(str(i) for i in var4)` to explicitly make each item a type so that it's able to be printed